# Air Pressure on wheels

Tags: tire, wheels, performance

Does the perfect air pressure is related to the performance of bikes? If yes, what is the exact amount of pressure required on MTB, Hybrid, City Bikes and BMX?

Comment: Pressure does affect performance - you only need to imagine the extremes to see this. However "perfect" pressure would happen on a per-tyre basis.

Comment: @PeteH  and per cyslist?

Comment: Possibly. It would be interesting to see a graph on how the weight of a cyclist affected the area of tyre surface in contact with the road. I know that load can have an effect with cars, but car tyres generally run at far lower pressures than bicycles.

Comment: In general, on reasonably solid surfaces, you achieve the lowest rolling resistance with tires inflated to the maximum pressure listed on their sidewalls.  Lower pressure may be required off-road to provide "flotation" and traction on unstable surfaces (in addition to providing a more comfortable ride).

Comment: Maximum being optimal is only valid for perfectly smooth surfaces and cycling in a straight line.

Answer (score 5):

The optimum pressure for any kind of bike is going to depend on a lot more factors than just the type of bike. You have to look at many other things such as rider weight, terrain, and tire size. It also depends on how you qualify something as optimum. Higher pressures might be optimum in some situations, but may not be very comfortable to the rider, making long rides very hard on their body.

Answer (score 1):

Air pressre in your tyres is very significant in terms of performance; in case of slick tyres it's even more important than width. However it's impossible to arbitrally put any value of tyre pressure as perfect for a given bike. The tyre pressure adjustments can depend on:

- wheel size - smaller wheels need higher pressure because the overall volume of tyres and their contact patch is smaller thus the pressure of this patch on the ground is higher meaning it's easier to have a flat
- tyre width - again wider tyres have larger volume so they are harder to deform allowing for lower pressure
- rider and bike weight - if you're heavier you need higher pressure
- tyre weight - it's not always the case, but quite often lighter tyres have just thinner walls so need higher pressure to avoid flats
- rubber type and thread density - these can make a difference and make it possible for a light tyre to be ridden in low pressure
- required grip, terrain type, weather - lower pressure means higher grip and in really rough terrain can actually mean lower rolling resistance. But in such terrain you need not only grip, but alsoresistance to flats, which requires higher pressure
- rider experience, personal preferences
- tubeless, tubulars, clincher - tubeless tyres allow for lower pressure, as do tubulars
- rolling resistance vs grip - especially in road cycling higher pressure means significant decrease of rolling resistance, but can also mean lower grip (this can be made up for with  softer rubber). You may have to choose basing on your experience and requirements what you prefer.

I could have forgotten something, but these are the most important. So to conclude, some of these are really hard to be put in a fixed formula and given numerical values, and therefore it's impossible to say that a given pressure is perfect for a given bike. Even in professional cycling this is usually defined with trial and error method.

Comment: You forgot float.  It fits in with terrain.  And rider and bike weight is not necessarily correct for all riding styles.  Heavier riders on fatbikes generally need to run lower pressure to achieve the same flotation as lighter riders.

Answer (score 0):

Of course it's related: more pressure -> less contact with surface which gives less friction. But for the the exact pressure I think you should refer to the tire. Usually it's written on the tire.

Comment: Contact area does not influence friction. Lower pressure means higher elastic deformation of the tyre which is directly responsible for higher rolling resistance. 
Also in case of rubber being a deformable material, apart from friction there is a significant phenomenon of adhesion, which is often mistaken with friction and is dependent on contact area. Adhesion and friction are responsible for better grip of a tyr and can be linked to rolling resistance, but it's not a direct link.

Comment: Also, if the pressure is too high, then the tire will be unable to absorb irregularities in the riding surface. In a velodrome, pressures around 180 psi are not uncommon, but on the road this is unheard of because it would be uncomfortable, but would also require the  bicycle to be lifted over the  bumps, causing quite a bit more lost energy than simply having the tire deform around small bumps.

Answer (score -2):

MTB Tire Pressure (PSI) Made Easy
Individual preferences, terrain, and tire type play a role in finding the ideal pressure, but here's a simple formula to get you started:

Step One
If tires are tubeless:
Your body weight (lbs) ÷ 7 = x

Step Two
Front-tire pressure = x - 2
Rear-tire pressure = x + 1

Comment: Weight is not measured in the same units as pressure. There needs to be a conversion in here somewhere.

Comment: and 1 and 2 don't have any units which is again different to both weight and pressure.

Comment: Assuming x is in bar or PSI, as those are the common units used, then, having an x value of 90 would mean that the front tire is at 89 PSI, and the rear tire is at 92 PSI.  You might as well just call it x, as most pumps don't even measure that accurately, as 2 psi is not going to make a huge difference. If we are talking bar, then then we have an x value of 6.2 bar (90 psi) and we have the front tire at 5.2 bar and a rear tire at 8.2 bar, which is too much of a difference to be reasonable. Also, I can't seem to get a value for x that makes sense value no matter which units I use for weight.

Comment: @bdsl, I doubt it's ever going to work. I've tried kg & bar, and pounds & psi, and both lead to nonsense numbers. Pounds & psi is closer but (a) who'd bother with +/- 1--2 psi and (b) it seems quite low unless the tyres are very wide, and I'd assume a difference of at least 1.5x in width between mtb tyres.

Comment: In addition to what's already been mentioned in the comments, this doesn't account for tire width at all. It's an interesting idea, but it really needs some clarification and further variables.

Comment: This is what I run on both my MTB's (26" and 29"): 

Tubeless:
200/7=28.6
Front-27psi
Rear-30psi

Tubes:
200/6=33.3
Front-32
Rear-35